# How to generate an IAM policy from a lambda authorizer restricting access to specific API endpoints?

Tags: amazon-web-services, jwt, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, lambda-authorizer

I would like make a Lambda authorizer, that validates a jwt token issued by a third party IDP (Onelogin for instance), generate an IAM policy restricting a user access to specific API endpoints from the API gateway based on permissions extracted from the jwt token. I would like also to make the API Gateway cache the generated policy so that requests coming from the same user don't need to be passed to the authorizer and could be accepted or rejected based on the cached policy. Is such a scenario possible? If it is, I would appreciate any guidance on how to configure it.

Thank you!

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/apigateway-use-lambda-authorizer.html#api-gateway-lambda-authorizer-types) help?.